# How to add colon to the end of the word using extension

Tags: flutter, extension-methods

13

I would like to add colon to a Dart word in a given position using extension, exactly like this (In flutter).
example:

Name:   and Password:

Name:
Password:
No:
Price:

we are use Uppercase and Lowercase in dart same as I try use in colon(:) same like this type any word and use colon extension how can I create this please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new extension for string like below: This will capitalised your word and add colon at end of the word:

```
extension StringExtension on String {
  String toCapitalized() => length > 0
      ? '${this[0].toUpperCase()}${substring(1).toLowerCase()}:'
      : '';
}
```

Use:

```
Text("name".toCapitalized()),
Text("password".toCapitalized()),
```